# SQLite Cipher does not install on Galaxy Note 5

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, sqlcipher

We are using an encrypted SQLCipher database in our Android app (internal memory, not on SD card), compiled in (SDK23) and we are facing issues with the app crashing IMMEDIATELY when "installation" starts when we install it on our Galaxy Note 5 (running Android 6.0.2).

On other devices (Sony Xperia S, running Android 4.1.2, Sony Z5, running Android 6) NO problems - apk installs and app runs. We only see this on our Galaxy Note 5. When we use the same database without Cipher (also in internal memory, not on SD card) then it ALSO works on the Galaxy Note 5. So, this issue is Cipher related and as we only see it on the Galaxy.

Comment: Please provide specific details about what "app crashing IMMEDIATELY when "installation" starts" means, such as stack traces, a [mcve], steps for reproducing the problem, etc.

Comment: We will integrate crashanalytics/fabric now to get more details. So far, as developers dont have the Galaxy HW themselves, but tested on several non-Galaxy devices with no problems, we unfortunately have no more technical details as of now (as said, we will integrate crashanalytics/fabric to get more details). At the moment, :"crashing immediately on installation" means just that: after APK downloaded and "install" clicked, the installation crashes immediately

Comment: It is is truly crashing at install time, Crashlytics should not help. That can only help when your app is crashing, and your app is not even running while it is being installed. Most likely, you will need to get your hands on this hardware to be able to run some local tests.

Comment: I see the Galaxy Note 5 has an ARM64-v8A Instruction set. and I see here(https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-for-android-native-library-support/1440): "SQLCipher for Android currently includes support for armeabi, armeabi-v7a, and x86 only. At this time we do not include support for either arm64, or x86_64 as OpenSSL does not currently build on those platforms without modification of the standard OpenSSL build system. We currently expect OpenSSL to include support for arm64 and x86_64 with the 1.1.0 release, which is not yet available." I guess that is the answer.... yes?